# How do I manually add a bean in Spring container and apply an advise to it without getting the bean from the container?

Tags: java, spring, playframework, playframework-2.2, spring-aop

I'm trying to apply an advise on Global.java in Play Framework.

The reason why I can't get the bean from the spring container is because this Global.java is being bootstrapped by the Play Framework and I can't possibly replace its instance manually.

Two possible solutions I could think of:

1. Find a method similar to `autowireBean(..)` that not only sets the
   autowirings but also advises stuff as well.
2. Find a way to replace
   the Global instance used by the Play Framework to bootstrap the app.

Here's my code snippet:

```
@Component( "global" )
public class Global {

    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Override
public void onStart(Application app) {
        this.ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( "spring-config.xml" );
        this.ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean( this );
    }


    @Override
public Action<?> onRequest(Request req, Method actionMethod) 
       return ....
    }
}


@Aspect
public class AspectDemo {

    @Around( "execution(* Global.onRequest(..))" )
    public Object myAround(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable
    {
        System.out.println( "advising around start");
        Object obj = jp.proceed();
            // do something about the obj...
        System.out.println( "advising around end");
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make `Global` a Spring bean (which would mean that you can therefore use Spring AOP), check out the `@Configurable` annotation. Basically with that annotation and some extra configuration, Spring can make any class it has not instantiated a managed bean.

Check out [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/spring-configurable-magic.html) and [this](http://tamasgyorfi.wordpress.com/2013/11/13/spring-dependency-injection-configurable/) for more details.